# How to mute the CS8602 warning if it's checked with the is-Operator before in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I do my best to check `null` values. But often, I try this with the `is`-Operator. While this, I expect, he will give `true` back only, if operand is a `not-null` value.

Example:

```
EndPoint endPoint = new();

if (endPoint is IPEndPoint)
    DoSomething(endPoint as IPEndPoint); // The "as" expressions give the CS8602 warning
```

...

```
void DoSomething(IPEndPoint endPoint)
{
    ...
}
```

With this, I get a [CS8602](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs8602) compiler warning, but `endPoint` is a `IPEndPoint` and the `as` expression can't be `null`. So IMHO, the compiler warning is wrong. How can I mute it for before checks with the `is`-Operator only?

(Maybe inside the `.editorconfig` anyhow?)

Comment: Here it seems that your cast is a useless task and there is no need to cast at all, but when you use as, it is possible that the result will be Null, but if you want to do this, you will not receive a warning in this way `DoSomething((IPEndPoint)endPoint)`

Comment: you shouldn't use `as` with `is` as you're wasting resources by trying to cast the object twice. Use direct cast `(IPEndPoint)endPoint` or better use cast right in the if statement `if (endPoint is IPEndPoint ipEndPoint) DoSomething(ipEndPoint)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is` and `as` are two separate casting operations and the compiler tries to cast and validate both of them, so it's reasonable to say warning `CS8602`.

As @Adassko said in the comment the best way is to cast the object once and use the casting result (if castable):

```cs
EndPoint endPoint = new();

if (endPoint is IPEndPoint endpoint)
    DoSomething(endpoint);
```